# Checkbox change function only firing once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Admittedly awful but trying to improve my jQuery skills and struggling with this issue. I have a few checkboxes that are being generated from an asp.net repeater, I'm trying to enforce only having one of these checkboxes checked at a time. I can get this working on jsFiddle but not in my solution, can anyone see anything that sticks out as being wrong?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ut3m6x1d/3/)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.menuBox input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
        $('.menuBox input[type=checkbox]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

HTML (generated by asp.net code):

```
<div class="menuBox">
   <div class="col1">
    <ul>
        <li id="ctl00_liCategory" class="liCategory">
            <input id="ctl00_chkCategory" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$chkCategory" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$chkCategory\',\'\')', 0)" />
            <label for="ctl00_chkCategory" id="ctl00_lblCategory">first label</label>
        </li>
        <li id="ctl01_liCategory" class="liCategory">
            <input id="ctl01_chkCategory" type="checkbox" name="ctl01$chkCategory" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl01$chkCategory\',\'\')', 0)" />
            <label for="ctl01_chkCategory" id="ctl01_lblCategory">second label</label>
        </li>
        <li id="ctl02_liCategory" class="liCategory">
            <input id="ctl02_chkCategory" type="checkbox" name="ctl02$chkCategory" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl02$chkCategory\',\'\')', 0)" />
            <label for="ctl02_chkCategory" id="ctl02_lblCategory">third label</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
   </div>    
</div>
```

ASP.NET code generating the html:

```
<div class="col1">
   <ul>
      <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrCategoriesCol1"    OnItemDataBound="rptrCategories_ItemDataBound">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <li runat="server" id="liCategory" class="liCategory">
               <asp:Checkbox runat="server" ID="chkCategory" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="FilterResults" CssClass="CategoryChkBox" />
               <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCategory" AssociatedControlID="chkCategory" />
            </li>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater> 
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use radio buttons?

Comment: This is not an answer, only a comment.  You should use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: Yeah, that was my initial idea but I can't touch this particular code, thank you though.

Comment: The logic looks correct but maybe you are not providing everything.   I would first look at the menuBox DIV and make sure it is not being closed prematurely (which would cause the other columns of checkboxes not to change since those wouldn't match the selector).  Try changing your selector to `$('.menuBox input[type=checkbox]')` while debugging.

Comment: Ehh - what's that little `onclick="setTimeout(__doPostBack)"` guy doing? Is your page posting back each checkbox change?

Comment: yes it's posting back and updating the DOM one each checkbox change, I'm wondering if that's what is causing the issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a repeater, why not use a set of radio buttons instead, as you can only have one checked by default.

The only thing you will need is all of the inputs to have the same name

```
<input type="radio" name="list1" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="list1" value="2"/>
<input type="radio" name="list1" value="3"/>
<input type="radio" name="list1" value="4" />
<input type="radio" name="list1" value="5"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/314jm9oc/

```
$('.cbox').click(function() {
    $('.cbox').prop("checked",false);
    $(this).prop("checked",true);
});
```

Is a simple version of your checkbox issue, if you stick with checkbox's

```
$('.menuBox input[type=checkbox]').attr('onclick','');
$('.menuBox input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {   
   $('.menuBox input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked",false);
    $(this).prop("checked",true);
});
```

Will fit your provided example.

Haven't used .net webforms in a while.
But if you add

```
OnClick="JavaScript:EnableDisable(this);"
```

To your checkbox's

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function EnableDisable(ele) {
   $('.menuBox input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
     $(this).prop("checked",false");
   });
   ele.checked = true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: the asp.net repeater will change the input names so they won't match, I could try through jQuery to change the names back to match each other.

Comment: @MannfromReno can you explain a little more what you mean? As the code at the bottom doesn't take into account name. Sticking with checkbox's. Also if you wanted to use radios : http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_radiobuttonlist.asp instead of a repeater.

Comment: Sure, so I've tried the radiobutton and name route and it hasn't worked because the repeater will generate different names for each input element. Your jQuery involving checkboxes removes my inline onclick event but then works to limit only one checked box, so I can get one or the other to work but not together.

Comment: What is the purpose of the inline onclick event? Did you need the page to post back after every change?

Comment: Yes, it's generated from the `AutoPostBack="true"`property in the `asp:Checkbox`

Comment: @MannfromReno updated my answer, not sure if it will actually work.

Comment: @MannfromReno there is a `GroupName` property on the radio button to group them together in a repeater.

Comment: Ben thank you, that seems to work very well, I'll have to inspect further tomorrow but I'm accepting yours right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the blank html and it should work just like in jsFiddle

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
  $('.menuBox input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    $('.menuBox input[type=checkbox]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
}); 
</script>

<div class="menuBox">
<div class="col1">
<ul>
    <li id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol1_ctl00_liCategory" class="liCategory">
        <input id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol1_ctl00_chkCategory" type="checkbox" name="content_0$rptrCategoriesCol1$ctl00$chkCategory" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'content_0$rptrCategoriesCol1$ctl00$chkCategory\',\'\')', 0)" />
        <label for="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol1_ctl00_chkCategory" id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol1_ctl00_lblCategory">first label</label>
    </li>
    <li id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol1_ctl01_liCategory" class="liCategory">
        <input id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol1_ctl01_chkCategory" type="checkbox" name="content_0$rptrCategoriesCol1$ctl01$chkCategory" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'content_0$rptrCategoriesCol1$ctl01$chkCategory\',\'\')', 0)" />
        <label for="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol1_ctl01_chkCategory" id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol1_ctl01_lblCategory">second label</label>
    </li>
    <li id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol1_ctl02_liCategory" class="liCategory">
        <input id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol1_ctl02_chkCategory" type="checkbox" name="content_0$rptrCategoriesCol1$ctl02$chkCategory" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'content_0$rptrCategoriesCol1$ctl02$chkCategory\',\'\')', 0)" />
        <label for="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol1_ctl02_chkCategory" id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol1_ctl02_lblCategory">third label</label>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col2">
<ul>
    <li id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol2_ctl00_liCategory" class="liCategory">
        <input id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol2_ctl00_chkCategory" type="checkbox" name="content_0$rptrCategoriesCol2$ctl00$chkCategory" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'content_0$rptrCategoriesCol2$ctl00$chkCategory\',\'\')', 0)" />
        <label for="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol2_ctl00_chkCategory" id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol2_ctl00_lblCategory">fourth label</label>
    </li>
    <li id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol2_ctl01_liCategory" class="liCategory">
        <input id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol2_ctl01_chkCategory" type="checkbox" name="content_0$rptrCategoriesCol2$ctl01$chkCategory" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'content_0$rptrCategoriesCol2$ctl01$chkCategory\',\'\')', 0)" />
        <label for="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol2_ctl01_chkCategory" id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol2_ctl01_lblCategory">fifth label</label>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col3">
<ul>
    <li id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol3_ctl00_liCategory" class="liCategory">
        <input id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol3_ctl00_chkCategory" type="checkbox" name="content_0$rptrCategoriesCol3$ctl00$chkCategory" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'content_0$rptrCategoriesCol3$ctl00$chkCategory\',\'\')', 0)" />
        <label for="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol3_ctl00_chkCategory" id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol3_ctl00_lblCategory">sixth label</label>
    </li>
    <li id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol3_ctl01_liCategory" class="liCategory">
        <input id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol3_ctl01_chkCategory" type="checkbox" name="content_0$rptrCategoriesCol3$ctl01$chkCategory" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'content_0$rptrCategoriesCol3$ctl01$chkCategory\',\'\')', 0)" />
        <label for="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol3_ctl01_chkCategory" id="content_0_rptrCategoriesCol3_ctl01_lblCategory">seventh label</label>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on JFiddle because, since you set Framework & extensions option to `jQuery 1.7.2`, it's included inside a `$(document).ready(...);` statement. In order it to work everywhere you only have to do the same on your own:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.menuBox input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
          $('.menuBox input[type=checkbox]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I edited my code above, this was already in a document ready statement in my code.